# Jquery: How can I click a button by selecting text inside a button with no id or span

Tags: cucumber, bdd

```
<div class="row" >
<button type="submit" class="cl-button cl-button--no cl-column">No</button>
<div class="row" >
<button type="submit" class="cl-button cl-column">Yes</button>
```

I am trying to click a button by fetching text. As they have same class I find no other option. Any ideas?
I have tried:

```
$('div:contains("No")').click()
$(':No').click()
$(':contains("No")').click()
$('button:contains("No")')
```

but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Have you tried `text() == "No"`?

Comment: I couldnt succeed with text(). I may have been making a typo but I am not sure what is wrong

Comment: The xpath would be `//button[text()='No']`

Comment: @BillHileman - thanks - I'm not an xpath expert - I went psuedo-code-ish instead.

Comment: Assuming it solved your problem I will add it as an answer instead of a comment so that it can be marked as a solution.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following xpath to locate the "No" button:

```
//button[text()='No']
```

Answer (score 1):

To identify the element using the text

```
//button[contains(text(),'Yes')]

//button[contains(text(),'No')]
```

Use these **XPath** to access the elements.

Answer (score 0):

"No" button has an extra class, you could try css with:

```
button.cl-button--no
```